# Laravel How to download all files in a directory

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

Using Laravel, I am trying to make a function which would download all files in a directory from S3.

I have used to retrieve all keys of the files using `$file = Storage::disk('s3')->allFiles('path');`, but I do not know what to do next.

It seems like I have to download all files into local, then zip those files, then download that zip file. I would like to know if there is a better way.

Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do what I wanted with this:

http://coderaweso.me/zip-and-download-files-directory-from-amazon-s3-with-laravel/

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to send more than one file simultaneously over the same request with the HTTP protocol. Laravel also does not support this. You have to pack the files in, for example, a zip file.

Install [Chumper/Zipper](https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper) package and return a zip  containing all your files:

```
$files = Storage::disk('s3')->allFiles('path');
Zipper::make(public_path('test.zip'))->add($files);

return response()->download(public_path('test.zip'));
```